# Power BI - Cumulative Running Total Percentage Complete by Month

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report to track a project with multiple sub-tasks. I need to track a cumulative percentage complete by month in an area chart. I have one table that lists my sub-tasks with their respective status and completion date. All sub-tasks have a status (Not Started, In Process or Complete). Completion date is blank if the item hasn't been completed. I have a separate Date table ("Date") that links its date to the completion date in my other table ("NA GSO"). I've tried building measures, quick measures, etc. with zero luck and am really struggling here. My brain says that I can just do a count of sub-tasks that have a completion date within a specific month, but I'm not savvy enough with Power BI to figure out how to show that as a running total percentage in an area chart.

I've tried several measures (all of which I then deleted in frustration).

Comment: Add your sample data in tabular format and expected output.